# Why some part of my pie chart is missing in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data is

```
> dput(df2_m)
structure(list(FY = c("2018-19", "2019-20", "2018-19", "2019-20", 
"2018-19", "2019-20", "2018-19", "2019-20"), Finance_Type = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("DF_Bank", "DF_O", "DE_SC", 
"DF_E"), class = "factor"), value = c(42029, 47363, 3000, 3000, 
26197, 27000, 50016, 63848)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Two pie charts I am creating with ggplot with the following commands:

```
# Create a basic bar first
  library(ggplot2)
  pie = ggplot(df2_m, aes(x="", y=value, fill = Finance_Type)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", width=1)

  pie <- pie + facet_grid(facets =. ~ FY) # Side by side bar chart
  pie <- pie + coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0) # side by side pie chart
  pie <- pie + geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(value/(sum(value))*100), "%")), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))

# Add color scale (hex colors)
# pie = pie + scale_fill_manual(values=c("#55DDE0", "#33658A", "#2F4858", "#F6AE2D", "#F26419", "#999999")) 

# Remove labels and add title
  pie = pie + labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = NULL, title = "Deficit Finance - Source")

# Tidy up the theme
  pie = pie + theme_classic() + theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, color = "#666666"))

 pie
```

The problem is that a part of my first pie chart is missing. How can I get two complete pie charts?

Comment: should be solved when you use `position = "fill"` in `geom_bar`

Comment: if I use geom_bar(stat = "identity", width=1, position = "fill") I get the full pie, but after adding the geom_text command the pies are lost.

Comment: I have the same problem with geom_text as @AmirulIslam

Comment: Update: It works when I input position = "fill" into geom_text!